# rellenar un Array de objetos en un constructor? JAVA

Tags: java

me han puesto un ejercicio donde tengo que declarar un array de 40 espacios (en la clase hija), y hacer que lo rellenen en el constructor de una clase hija.

El problema empieza cuando intento compilar la clase hija , creo un constructor sin parámetros, fuera de el declaro el array de clase padre, y una vez dentro le hago un bucle for para rellenarlo pero me dice que no he puesto parámetros a Carta aun haciendo lo:

```
private Carta baraja[]=new Carta[40];

//CONSTRUCTOR

public BarajaESP()
{   
//int cont=0;   //para referirnos a la posicion
    
    
    for(int cont=0;cont<baraja.length;cont++)
    {   
        
        baraja[cont]=new Carta(1,"espadas");
        cont++;
    
    }
    
}
```

Al compilar esta clase hija, me salta el siguiente error:

```
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: El constructor del padre como es?

Comment: //constructor
 
 public Carta(int valor, String palo)
 {
  if(valor>=1 && valor<=12 && (palo.equalsIgnoreCase("bastos") || palo.equalsIgnoreCase("copas") || palo.equalsIgnoreCase("espadas") || palo.equalsIgnoreCase("oros")) )
  {
  this.valor=valor;
  this.palo=palo;
  }else
  {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Valor no valido!!");
  }
  
 }

Comment: Agrega el código de la clase padre y también el código de donde estas llamando a estos constructores. Es posible que estés llamando al constructor incorrecto o estés pasando mal los parámetros. Otra cosa que observo, estas haciendo 2 cont++, de esta forma solo vas a cargar 20 cartas.

Comment: Hola, la clase padre es Carta, y la hija BarajaEsp, el constructor de la clase padre tiene un int , String y es lo que pongo al rellenar el array, pero me sigue diciendo que está vacia, así que simplemente le he quitado el ExTENDS para que ya no sea hija y de momento parece que funciona

Comment: P.D: tenias razón en lo del cont, es que lo había metido antes en un metodo que he creado para ver si así funcionaba poero como no lo ha hecho lo he vuelto a pegar todo en el constructor

Comment: BarajaESP debe ser hija de Carta ? Usualmente en este ejercicio Carta es un campo de la clase BarajaESP.

Comment: En realidad, no especifica que lo tenga que ser, es que en el mismo enunciado ha pedido clase "CartaBrisca" especificando que debería ser hija, y luego "BarajaESP" no ha dicho nada, pero padre de carta seguro que no es...

Answer (score 0):

Mirando tus comentarios te planteo una respuesta que puede sacarte dudas y solucionar el problema, sacar los `Extends` no es solución, ya que, estarías dejando de usar herencia y no podrías hablar de clase padre y clase hija, solo serian 2 clases sin relación.

Te planteo otro ejemplo donde voy a usar una clase padre computadora y 2 clases hijas:

```
public class Computadora 
{
    private int atributoX;

    public Computadora (int param)
    {
        //toda la lógica que necesites
    }
}
```

Este seria el codigo de las clases hijas:

```
public class Escritorio extends Computadora
{
    public int array[] = new int [40];   
    public Escritorio()
    {
    }    
}

public class Notebook extends Computadora
{
    public Notebook(int param)
    {
        
    }           
}
```

Como observas las 2 clases hijas tienen distintos constructores, a su vez, la clase Notebook esta recibiendo un int como parametro, al igual que el padre. Aunque esto sea asi, estas 2 clases no van a compilar por el simple hecho de que los constructores no se heredan entre jerarquias de clases. Aca es donde entra en juego la palabra reservada super(). Tampoco debes olvidar que al redefinir un constructor, el constructor por defecto ya no vale mas.
En este ejemplo, para que las 2 clases hijas compilen el código de las clases debería ser este:

```
public class Computadora 
{
    private int atributoX;
    
    public Computadora ()
    {
        //constructor sin parametro
    }
    public Computadora (int param)
    {
        //constructor con parametro
    }
}

public class Notebook extends Computadora
{
    public Notebook(int param)
    {
        super(param);
    }           
}

public class Escritorio extends Computadora
{
    public int array[] = new int [40];   
    public Escritorio()
    {
        super();
    }    
}
```

Para mas info, busca el tema de Herencia y las palabras reservadas `super()` y `this()`.

Comment: Hola Franco, muchas gracias x tu respuesta esta muy bien elaborada, pero el enunciado del ejercicio nos especifica que hay que crear un constructor SIN parámetros, que rellene el array de clase Carta, te lo dejo a continuación haber si yo me he perdido alguna parte:

Comment: Haz otra clase llamada BarajaESP para crear una baraja de cartas españolas (o mazo de
cartas). Una baraja española tiene 40 cartas/naipes. Las operaciones que podrá realizar una
baraja:
• Construirse: un solo constructor sin parámetros, crea e inicializa un array de 40 cartas
(AS, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, sota, caballo y rey) de cada palo (bastos, copas, espadas y oros).
Inicializa un entero que indique las cartas que aún quedan sin usar. Imagina que la carta

Comment: Si comprendo, si vas a utilizar un constructor sin parámetros en la clase HIJA, estas obligado a crearlo en la clase PADRE. Entiendo que por ahí los ejercicios plantean cosas forzadas, pero ahí es donde entra la lógica y donde los profes muchas veces fallan. Para que utilizar herencia si no va usar su beneficios, recorda que le herencia así como tiene beneficios tiene muchas contras también.

Comment: puede ser, no me han especificado que esa clase concreta tenga que ser heredada